# Changing current windows language in intellij idea

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea

At my primary pc i am changing current language using shift+alt(i believe that this is default for windows) but on another pc(it is not mine, but im allowed to code on it) it is done by shift+ctrl and it is uncomfortable. Can i add or maybe there is already a key shortcut in intellij that i can change to "emulate" shift+alt?

Comment: I mean the language i use to type code/text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortcut for changing an OS input language is a Global shortcut and cannot be changed inside the applications.